# Find Date Range Of First, Second, Third & Fourth Week In A Month

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar, recurring-events

[enter image description here][1]I'm in a situation where i need to find date range of First, Second, Third & Fourth Week (i.e we can say Nth week) in a month. Its a booking website where i want to give an option of creating an event which repeats on every Nth week's Nth days.

E.g

- Event Title - Two days Yoga Classes
- Start Date  - 1/June/2017
- End Date    - 31/July/2017
- Event Days  - Monday & Friday
- Repeat On   - Every Second Week

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XysBp.png -- create event

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN8sE.png -- book event

Comment: How do you define "week of month"? Is Saturday 1 July in the 5th week of June or first week of July? Typically weeks are numbered from the first Monday of the month, so 1 June 2017 is in week 5 of May 2017.

Comment: So the week number is just `Math.ceil(dayNumber / 7)`. Great. How does the rest of it work? How does a user select "*an event which repeats on every Nth week's Nth days*"? What is input? What is output? Where are the examples? What have you tried?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XysBp.png -- create event ,   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN8sE.png -- book event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (var i = range.start.getTime(), end = range.end.getTime(); i <= end;) {
            var first   = new Date(i);
            var last    = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth() + 1, 0); // last day of the month
            if(item.recurring_type == 'every_week') {
                // in case of repetition every week
                ranges.push({
                    start: moment(formatDate(first),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    end: moment(formatDate(last),'YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month'),
                })
            } else if(item.recurring_type == 'first_week') {
                // 1 to 7
                var cus_date_start = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 1);
                var cus_date_end = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 7);
                if( cus_date_start.getDate() >= first.getDate() && cus_date_end.getDate() <= last.getDate() ) {
                    ranges.push({
                        start: moment(formatDate(cus_date_start),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end: moment(formatDate(cus_date_end),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    })
                }
            } else if(item.recurring_type == 'second_week') {
                // 8 to 14
                var cus_date_start = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 8);
                var cus_date_end   = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 14);
                if( cus_date_start.getDate() >= first.getDate() && cus_date_end.getDate() <= last.getDate() ) {
                    ranges.push({
                        start: moment(formatDate(cus_date_start),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end: moment(formatDate(cus_date_end),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    })
                }
            } else if(item.recurring_type == 'third_week') {
                // 15 to 21
                var cus_date_start = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 15);
                var cus_date_end   = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 21);
                if( cus_date_start.getDate() >= first.getDate() && cus_date_end.getDate() <= last.getDate() ) {
                    ranges.push({
                        start: moment(formatDate(cus_date_start),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end: moment(formatDate(cus_date_end),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    })
                }
            } else {
                // 22 to end
                var cus_date_start = new Date(first.getFullYear(), first.getMonth(), 22);

                ranges.push({
                    start: moment(formatDate(cus_date_start),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    end: moment(formatDate(last),'YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('month'),
                })
            }

            i = last.getTime() + aDay;
        }
```

This is the solution i've made that is close but not accurate, if anyone can improve this code then please post your answers.

Thank you